# What's the difference between a TSO Authorization and a letter of TSO design approval?

Tags: faa-regulations

FAA can issue two types of approval for a [TSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Standard_Order) part application: TSO Authorization and letter of TSO design approval. What's the difference?

Does it relate to the approval being design-only or production only?

Also, do other Airworthiness Authorities have a similar difference?

According to [14 CFR 21 Subpart O §21.601](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=228becec6aaeb9af32e1ae37516c266a&mc=true&node=se14.1.21_1601&rgn=div8):

> (2) A TSO authorization is an FAA design and production approval
>   issued to the manufacturer of an article that has been found to meet a
>   specific TSO;
>
> (3) A letter of TSO design approval is an FAA design approval for an
>   article that has been found to meet a specific TSO in accordance with
>   the procedures of § 21.621;
>
> (4) An article manufactured under a TSO authorization, an FAA letter
>   of acceptance as described in § 21.613(b), or an article manufactured
>   under a letter of TSO design approval described in § 21.621 is an
>   approved article for the purpose of meeting the regulations of this
>   chapter that require the article to be approved;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about this, but it looks like a TSO Authorization is for domestic (US) manufacturers, and a letter of TSO design approval is for foreign manufacturers who want to import their products into the US. See [21.621](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=06cb85faf1518dc6f41fc6508a75c28c&mc=true&n=sp14.1.21.o&r=SUBPART&ty=HTML#se14.1.21_1621):

> **§21.621   Issue of letters of TSO design approval: Import articles.**
>
> (a) The FAA may issue a letter of TSO design approval for an article—
>
> (1) Designed and manufactured in a foreign country or jurisdiction
>   subject to the export provisions of an agreement with the United
>   States for the acceptance of these articles for import; and
>
> (2) For import into the United States if— [...]

And [the FAA's page](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/tso/tso_design_app/) on it says:

> **What is a letter of design approval?**
>   An FAA design approval for an article manufactured outside the United States that meets a
>   specific TSO.

I have no idea about other aviation authorities, but I assume there are similar regulations in other countries because the same general issue exists everywhere: how do you ensure that both manufactured and imported aviation components meet all required standards?

Comment: As for your last question, dealing with imported parts is quite a tough problem as it depends on specific agreements between countries. See https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/international-cooperation-overview